# How to do a majority voting on three dataframe in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have three Dataframe (dataframe1, dataframe2, dataframe3)

```
import pandas as pd
data1= [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1,0,1,0], [0,1,1,0], [1,1,0,1]]
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['0', '1', '2', '3'])
dataframe1
data2 = [[1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,1], [0,0,0,1]]
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['0', '1', '2', '3'])
dataframe2
data3 = [[1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,1]]
dataframe3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns=['0', '1', '2', '3'])
dataframe3
```

I need a new data frame based on the majority element on each position of above three dataframe

Expected outcome

1 0 1 0

0 0 1 0

0 1 0 0

0 1 0 1

Comment: *based on the majority element on each position* - could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because same index values in each DataFrame is possible use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then per indices get majority element by [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html), if possible multiple majority elements and need one select first value by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([dataframe1, dataframe2, dataframe3])
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  1  0
1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  1
```